# Cannot resolve relative URL

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

When I use a relative url in an SCSS file (I am trying to set the background-image property to a local file), I receive the following error:

[image]

Any idea how what is going wrong?

I have a project with the following structure:

```
public/
    dist/
    images/
        wave.png
    index.html
src/
    components/
        MyComponent.js
    app.js
styles/
    base/
    components/
        _my-component.scss
    styles.scss
webpack.config.js
```

In *MyComponent.js* I render `<div className="bg"></div>`.

In *_my-component.scss* I have:

```
.bg {
    background-image: url("/images/wave.png");
}
```

And in *webpack.config.js* I have:

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isProduction = env === "production";

    return {
        entry: ["./src/app.js"],
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, "public", "dist"),
            filename: "bundle.js"
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                },
                {
                    test: /\.s?css$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        {
                            loader: "css-loader",
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: "sass-loader",
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "styles.css"
            })
        ],
        devtool: isProduction ? "source-map" : "inline-source-map",
        devServer: {
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
            historyApiFallback: true,
            publicPath: "/dist/"
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: You are missing a dot at the begnining: `background-image: url("./images/wave.png");`

Comment: I tried changing to any of:  `"./images/wave.png"`, `"./public/images/wave.png"`, `"../public/images/wave.png"` and still see the same error

Answer (score 0):

In `_my-component.scss`, directories are only relative to this file. According to your directory tree, you would need to go up 2 directories, which is essentially back to the root/home directory, and then one directory down to the public folder.

Try this path in your script: `../../public/images/wave.png`

Comment: I just tied your suggestion. The previous error is gone, and now I have a new error `Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file`

Comment: [This might help with that] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556862/moduleparseerror-module-parse-failed-unexpected-character)